# If Kubuntu is based on Ubuntu, then why does its installation give me problems?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu

This might be an ignorant question, but I tried Kubuntu recently. I've heard that it merely has a different interface, but the backend is essentially Ubuntu.

Yet, when I installed it, my sound didn't work properly and it didn't ask me to install the Nvidia drivers.

Installing Ubuntu, however, was a breeze. Everything works and the Software Updater tells me what to install.

Is Kubuntu's backend different to Ubuntu's?

Comment: Traditional answer: ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages ): "Kubuntu-desktop: Similar to ubuntu-desktop, but with KDE and related software instead of Gnome/Unity".

Comment: Here the Kubuntu is working fine. How did you install ? From the Kubuntu CD ? Or from the Ubuntu CD and then added the kubuntu desktop ? What kind of hardware do you have ? What version of the 'buntu did you install ? What kind of hardware do you have ? If you want to give feedback: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/11.10-release -> https://wiki.kubuntu.org/OneiricOcelot/Final/Kubuntu/Feedback.

Comment: The KDE window manager is not just a different theme for ubuntu, but a totally different software suite that controls the user experience. Things like package management, booting, running of services etc are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fewer developers work on the Kubuntu desktop than on the Ubuntu desktop, so sometimes polish such as "make it automatically open the hardware drivers window if needed" doesn't get done for both. The ability to install those drivers by opening the tool through the menu is still there.

As to sound, KDE has an additional sound layer on top of the Pulse Audio that Ubuntu and Kubuntu both include. Check your Multimedia settings in System Settings to be sure it's setup to go through Pulse Audio.